# What does -s mean in npm command?

Tags: npm, package.json

I saw the following command that includes `-s` option. What does it(`-s`) mean? Because I didn't see the option in `package.json`.

```
$ npm run dev -s
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The flag `-s` stands for "silent" and is applied to `npm`, not to the command in the `dev` script.

The `-s` flag prevents `npm` from screaming at you when the command exits with a non-zero status, i.e. when the command fails. It also won't create an npm_debug.log file.

To test out the difference yourself you can do the following in a new directory.

```
npm init -y
npm run test
npm run test -s
```

> Note 1: I prefer to write `npm run -s dev` to limit possible confusion.
>
> Note 2: To pass the `-s` flag to the `dev` script, you would run `npm run dev -- -s`.