# What does the `-s --` flag do for npm?

Tags: bash, npm, yarnpkg, flags, npm-scripts

I just watched a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CMILpbL6e88) by Kent C. Dodds where he explains his [`.bash_profile`.](https://github.com/kentcdodds/dotfiles/blob/master/.bash_profile)

He uses the following aliases for `yarn` and `npm`:

```
## npm aliases
alias ni="npm install";
alias nrs="npm run start -s --";
alias nrb="npm run build -s --";
alias nrd="npm run dev -s --";
alias nrt="npm run test -s --";
alias nrtw="npm run test:watch -s --";
alias nrv="npm run validate -s --";
alias rmn="rm -rf node_modules";
alias flush-npm="rm -rf node_modules && npm i && say NPM is done";
alias nicache="npm install --prefer-offline";
alias nioff="npm install --offline";

## yarn aliases
alias yar="yarn run";
alias yas="yarn run start -s --";
alias yab="yarn run build -s --";
alias yat="yarn run test -s --";
alias yav="yarn run validate -s --";
alias yoff="yarn add --offline";
alias ypm="echo \"Installing deps without lockfile and ignoring engines\" && yarn install --no-lockfile --ignore-engines"
```

I was wondering, what does the `-s --` flag do? Kent does not explain it in the video and I couldn't find any [info](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) on the flag(s).

Comment: That's two flags. By convention, `-s` is the shorthand for `--silent`. `--` is just the end of the args to `run` and the start of the args to whatever you're running. See https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script.html (not the install docs, for which that isn't used).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does -- do when running an npm command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43046885/what-does-do-when-running-an-npm-command)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/q/41383247/3001761

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Option `-s` makes `yarn` don't output anything on standard output, ie. silences it.

The `--` comes from [posix utility conventions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html) and is very common among command line linux tools:

```
Guideline 10:
The first -- argument that is not an option-argument should be accepted as a delimiter indicating the end of options. Any following arguments should be treated as operands, even if they begin with the '-' character.
```

So:

```
> printf "%s" -n
-n
```

All ok, it will print `-n`. But:

```
> printf -n
bash: printf: -n: invalid option
printf: usage: printf [-v var] format [arguments]
```

To allow passing `-n`, ie. option starting with a leading `-` as the first argument to printf, one can use `--`:

```
> printf -- -n
-n
```

So:

```
alias yas="yarn run start -s";
yas -package
```

will throw unknown option by yarn, as it will try to parse `-p` as an option. Doing:

```
alias yas="yarn run start -s --";
yas -package
```

will throw unknown package by `yarn` as there is no package named `-package`. By using `--` the author effectively blocks the user (himself) from passing any additional options to yarn, as all following arguments will be interpreted as package names only.

Comment: What about capital S ? Is there a difference?

Comment: @ZakherMasri What about capital S? Difference comparing what to what?

Comment: The capital S to the small s (-s vs -S). Is it even case-sensitive?

Answer (score 4):

`-s` is equivalent to `--silent`.

`--` is common Unix convention signifying end of options. After that, even if an argument looks like an option, it will be considered a positional argument.

Answer (score 1):

It means the end of command options. Therefore, you can't use command options (such as `-s`) after double dash. However, you can, for example, list files to process by command.

[Explained here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean-also-known-as-bare-double-dash)

The `-s` option itself is short equivalent to `--loglevel=silent` which disables logging output.